# On compact topological group

Tags: general-topology, compactness, topological-groups

Must a compact topological group be metrizable? If not, is it separable?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. A sufficiently large power of $\mathbb T$ (or even of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$) is not metrizable and not separable.

Comment: "Sufficiently large" being, precisely, "uncountable."

Comment: Only for the metrizability. Hewitt-Marczewski-Pondiczeri Theorem implies that a Tychonov product of not greater than $\frak c$ separable spaces is separable.

Comment: Ah, good, surprises are nice, thanks for the non-obvious fact. I see the theorem's not an equivalence-is it difficult to show that a large enough product isn't separable, then?

Comment: Never mind, here's why should anyone else be interested. http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2010;task=show_msg;msg=0470.0002.0001.0001.0001.0001.0001.0001.0001.0001.0001

Comment: I never mind, because it is easy to show that $|X|\le\exp\exp d(X)$ for each Hausdorff space $X$ :-)
[Theorem 1.5.1 from Ryszard Engelking’s “General Topology” (Russian version, 1986)].